# code blocks not compiling empty c file in linux lite

Tags: c, linux, gcc, codeblocks, permission-denied

I am using linux Lite.  I have installed code Blocks. When i am creating any new project then it is working correctly. it compiling codes. But When any empty c file is creating and trying to compile then it is not working.Showing message that  permission denied.  I have checked the compiler setting for empty file. it is GNU GCC Compiler. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be happen due to root access. run code-blocks as root user and try it would be work.

Comment: i am new in linux. I didn't know how to run as root user. After googleing found that "sudo yourprogram" is a way. I tried this way but the problem remain same.

Comment: HI using "sudo codeblocks" you can run codeblocks as root user.

Comment: What happen when you do that ?

Comment: After typing "sudo codeblocks", it has opened. then i create an empty c file and try to compile but it shown the same message that '/home/linuxlite/C_SourceCodes/TestAsRootRun: permission denied

Comment: Have you save new empty file with .c extension ?

Comment: ohh..i didn't do that. In windows it take automatically c extension, but i didn't know that in Linux i have to do by my own. Now i has worked. And if it is not run as root user, it is working. Thanks....!

Comment: Yes, but it would be depend on IDE. So, problem is you create empty name with "testprogram" and you try to run it expected binary name is "testprogram" so both name would not same and creating problem.